# Javascript Ajax-Request on Android Browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, ajax

I have an login form on my own website. 
I send the userdate via plain-JavaScript AJAX-request to a PHP-backend, which is checking the credentials. 
**This is working fine with all of my browsers on PC and iPad.**
**My problem occurs on my Android-device** (I use Chrome and standard-browser there).

The problem is, that I have to send out the **AJAX-request** 2-times, to get an answer.

To prove this: I have an alert after sending out the request and an alert inside the answer callback-function. If I send out the first request, only the first alert pops up. If I send it out the second time, the second alert pops up too.

Is there a known bug (workaround) for this problem?

I think, code is not required, because I do nothing special, but here you have it.

---

Code snippets (plain JavaScript):

```
function loginStart(strURL, myForm, callback) 
{
      xmlhttpPostForm(strURL, myForm, callback);
      alert("sent out");
}

function loginEnd(result) 
{
      alert("returned");
}


function xmlhttpPostForm(strURL, myForm, callback) {

    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            callback(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
        else if (self.xmlHttpReq.status != 200){
            callback("Unknown error occured.");
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring(myForm));
}
```

PHP-Backend (removed functionality)

```
<?php

$retval = array();
$retval['msg'] = "Nothing special to minimize error-sources";
$retval['success'] = true;
echo json_encode($retval);

?>
```

The form:

```
<form method="post" name="login_form" onsubmit="loginStart('includes/ajax_login.php', this, loginEnd); return false;">
    <table id="login">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="center">Login</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="right">Username</td>
            <td class="left"><input id="inEmail" type="text" name="email"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="right">Password</td>
            <td class="left"><input id="inPass" type="password" name="password"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            <td class="left"><img class="loadbar" id="loginloader" src="images/loader-bar.gif"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

EDIT: As request by @Vivasaayi I added an additional alert.

```
self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert("Returned: " + self.xmlHttpReq.readyState + " " + self.xmlHttpReq.status);
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {

......
```

In the good case:

Alert: Returned: 2 200
       Returned: 3 200
       Returned: 4 200

In the worst case:

First click: 
Nothing

Second click: 
Alert: Returned: 2 200
       Returned: 3 200
       Returned: 4 200
       Returned: 4 200

Comment: Could you please add an alert like this and verify the state change event is fired.

function() {
        alert("Test");
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {

Comment: @Vivasaayi See my edited question. I appended it.

Comment: Ok.. could you please confirm that you have got the request (in server) for the click.. If so whether the server has sent response..

Comment: @Vivasaayi Now I waited after the first click. After about 30 seconds, I got the response. In the PHP-Backend I incremented a value to see, if the request is received. The PHP-Script received the request after 30 seconds and answered immediately. So the problem is, that the AJAX-Request takes really long to arrive at the  backend.